# How to convert my VBA named-range to looping code

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, named-ranges

In my VBA code example below I've manually created 3 named ranges where the ReportID_0XX from incrementally increases from ...01 to ...03,
and also incremented the ComparisonReport cell reference from $A$6 to $A$8

This was fine in the smaller scope, but now I need to do this for 60 instances effectively continuing the process 57 more times to create named ranges for "ReportID_001" to "ReportID_060" (add keep applicable leading zeros) and  have the cell reference start at $A$6 and end up at $A$65.

I've very new to naming ranges with VBA.

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ReportID_001", RefersTo:= _
"='ComparisonReport'!$A$6"
ActiveWorkbook.Names("ReportID_001").Comment = ""
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ReportID_002", RefersTo:= _
"='ComparisonReport'!$A$7"
ActiveWorkbook.Names("ReportID_002").Comment = ""
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ReportID_003", RefersTo:= _
"='ComparisonReport'!$A$8"
ActiveWorkbook.Names("ReportID_003").Comment = ""
```

Comment: Create a Range object that consist of all the cells you interested in, loop over these cells and assign them a named range. Keep a designated variable to keep track of a counter to include in your named range name.....but why named ranges of single cells? I hardly see that =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
   Dim xBk As Workbook, xRng As Range, xCel As Range, xCtr As Long, xRep As String

   Set xBk = ActiveWorkbook
   Set xRng = Range("A6:A66")  ' or whatever range you want
   For Each xCel In xRng.Cells
      xCtr = xCtr + 1
      xRep = "ReportID_" & Format(xCtr, "000")   ' Make it "0000" if > 99 Reports
      xBk.Names.Add Name:=xRep, RefersTo:="='ComparisonReport'!$A$" & (xCtr + 5)
      xBk.Names(xRep).Comment = ""
   Next xCel
End Sub
```

Comment: @Dion Glad it helps